# OneDrive app says spreadsheet is corrupted

Tags: applications, ms-office, onedrive

I have a spreadsheet in my OneDrive storage. Using the OneDrive app on a Samsung TabA tablet I can see the file, but if I try to open it it says the file is corrupted.

However, if I open OneDrive in a browser on the tablet I can look at the spreadsheet normally, so there's nothing wrong with the file on OneDrive.

Does anyone know if the OneDrive app has issues with certain Office documents? This particular spreadsheet has 168 worksheets - could that be a problem for the app?

Comment: See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Troubleshoot-OneDrive-for-Android-app-problems-734999fb-5060-4a43-94e0-9e61d6622069) for restrictions on file name

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I can confirm it is definitely a legitimate filename, and doesn't contain any restricted characters. It does contain spaces, but that also applies to other Office files which open normally with the app.